# Add class only for current parent

Tags: jquery

In the given list, I want when I  hit 'click, then the 'red' class should apply only for current 'li' when I hit 'click' under the second 'li' then the class applying both 'li' how to prevent this.

```js
$(".thumb").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".scroll-demo").addClass("red");
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/xgs7kwrt/3/

Answer (score 2):

add $(".scroll-demo").removeClass("red");

```
 $(".thumb").click(function() {
 $(".scroll-demo").removeClass("red");
 $(this).closest(".scroll-demo").addClass("red");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `parent()` for add class only to parent element. and remove a class to other element you can use `siblings()`

```js
$(".thumb").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass("red").siblings().removeClass("red");
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The `.parent()` part is already covered by OP by using `.closest` - you've added `.siblings` and `.removeClass` - *this* is the answer, nothing to do with using parent

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the red class from all anchors first and add class to the current targeted anchor.

```js
$(".thumb").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.scroll-demo a').removeClass('red');
  $(this).addClass("red");
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
  <li class="scroll-demo">List 1 <a href="javascript:;" class="thumb">Click</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Doesn't put `.red` on the `li` as OP requested

Comment: I dont see anywhere that is mentioned or did I miss anything?

Comment: It's not like OP has a lot of text to go through... "*the 'red' class should apply only for current 'li'* ..  *when I hit 'click' under the second 'li' then the class applying [to] both 'li'..*"